# WFS connect SSL handshake fails

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs

I'm running GeoServer on my own server at home. Everything works great usually but when I try to connect to WFS from QGIS over https I get a warning saying SSL Handshake Failed. This is probably because I have a self-signed certificate.

Do I have to pay for an authorized certificate or is there a way around this?

https works fine in the web browser.  I just have to click to accept the certificate. I really don't want to pay $70 a year for a certificate just to use my GIS server for my own personal experimental use.

Comment: You can probably import your cert into the client machine. How you do that is OS dependant - a google search will probably help though. If you're just doing this for experiments, maybe don't use TLS.